# Radio button change firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I've got a group of radio buttons. When the radio buttons are changed an event is fired. A check is made to see if a certain radio button was selected, if so a text box is displayed.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="span3">
          <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HearAboutUs, "radWebsite", new { @id = "radWebsite" }) Website</label>
          <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HearAboutUs, "radFromEmployee", new { @id = "radFromEmployee" }) An employee</label>
          <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HearAboutUs, "radEvent", new { @id = "radEvent" }) At an event</label>
          ...
          <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HearAboutUs, "radOther", new { @id = "radOther" }) Other</label>
     </div>
     <div class="span3">
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HearAboutUs)
     </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
$('input:radio[name="HearAboutUs"]').change(function () {
    $('input[type=radio].input-validation-error').parent().removeClass('error-label');

    if ($('#radOther').is(':checked')) {
        if ($('#HearAboutUsDescription').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#HearAboutUsDescription').show("blind");
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#HearAboutUsDescription').is(':visible')) {
            $('#HearAboutUsDescription').hide("blind");
            $('#HearAboutUsDescription').val('');
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine! However... This is a partial page that is being hidden and un-hidden when the user presses next/back respectively. After pressing next, and then back. The script to hide the text box somehow gets called twice!?! Not when it's shown however.
The code for the next/back which is on a main index page:

```
$('#nextBtn').click(function () {
    $('#panel1').hide("", function () {
        $('#panel2').show("blind");
        $('#backBtn').show();
    });
});

$('#backBtn').click(function () {

    if ($('#panel2').is(":visible")) {
        $('#headerTitle').text("Your Details");
        $('#panel2').hide("", function() {
            $('#panel1').show("blind");
            $('#backBtn').hide();
        });

    }
    if ($('#panel3').is(":visible")) {
        $('#headerTitle').text("About Your Home");
        $('#panel3').hide("", function() {
            $('#panel2').show("blind");
        });
    }
    if ($('#panel4').is(":visible")) {
        $('#headerTitle').text("Water Use In The House");
        $('#panel4').hide("", function() {
            $('#panel3').show("blind");
            $('#nextBtn').show();
            $('#nextBtn').html("Next");
        });
    }
});
```

Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong? I'm going slightly mad with this, heh :) Thanks

Edit = just noticed I pasted the next btn twice, replaced with back button. Also the buttons are on the index page, not the partial page.

Comment: where your backBtn, how it works?

Comment: The next and back buttons are on the index page. Along with the script to control those buttons. The script to hide/show the text box is on the partial page. It seems the hide/show functions re-bind the javascript events on the partial page so I'm either going to have to unbind the change event or override the hide/show functions to not re-bind the javascript it seems..
Unless there is a better way..

Comment: Which panel is the radiobutton group in?

Comment: The partial page Panel1. I've got a workaround which is to just unbind the events .unbind('change')

Comment: Okay, I set up a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/65K2a/) and I am unable to duplicate the problem, although I suspect it's because I'm either not interpreting your source correctly, or that there's other scripts missing that affect the source. Please take a look and post an updated fiddle if you can duplicate the issue. Also, I don't know which version of jQuery you're using so I used 1.7.2 so I could include the UI effects. Finally, 1.7.2 doesn't like an empty string for the `.hide `effect, so I used "default" so that the `.hide` method would work.

Comment: Look that you are not including twice the same javascript libraries